# How to execute Python program within @app.route without 405 error?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to execute this python back end program once I reach the handle data page. Why are the methods returning a 405 Method Not Allowed error?

In the past, I've tried changing the position of the python to outside of the @ decorator and the methods=["POST"] condition

Python

```
import random
import requests
import time
from datetime import date
import sys
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/handle_data") 
def handle_data():
        userName = requests.form['username']
        listName = requests.form['listname']

        full python code is here

        randomNumber = randint(0,len(nameList)-1)
        films = nameList[randomNumber]
        return render_template('home.html', films=films)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

...
HTML

```
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="POST">
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" size=15 name=username class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <input type="text" size=15 name=listname class="form-control" placeholder="List Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><input type = "submit" class="buttonclass" value = "Random!" /></p>
</form>
```

I expect the program to run the requests from the form through the program and return the random list item in form of the variable "films" but I receive a 405 error.
If you need more info, please notify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@app.route("/handle_data")` registers the route only for `GET` requests.  If you want `POST` too, you need to ask for it explicitly:

```py
@app.route("/handle_data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_data():
    # your code here
```

or:

```py
@app.route("/handle_data", methods=['GET'])
def handle_get_data():
    pass

@app.route("/handle_data", methods=['POST'])
def handle_post_data():
    pass
```

More here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#url-route-registrations